# Whitespaces in ios PWA title

Tags: javascript, ios, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA with 2 word title like "super app".

my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "super app",
  "short_name": "super app",
...
```

my index.html:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="super app" />
```

But when i install it on iphone, app icon on the home screen has title "superapp", without whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is probably happening because:

1. The name is being cached. Are you running on the localhost or this
   is your built version of the app? Consider cleaning Safari's cache
   on your iPhone from `settings -> Safari -> Clear History and Website Data` and try again. It's funny how Safari keeps a cached
   version of your app even in incognito mode as I was bothered with
   this for some hours!
2. Try removing npm cache using `npm cache clean --force` and then run `npm install` (or `npm update` if you want your
   packages to their latest version) again.

Finally, I recommend running your app on the localhost then launching your app from your iPhone on the same network. Then you can test it faster using hot reload. I am currently developing a PWA with React and I've just tested mine and it appears fine as "super app". Also [this](https://pwa-workshop.js.org/1-manifest/#manifest-fields) could really help.